# Parse an XML document using C# LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to parse this XML document -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data xmlns:data="report">
   <Report>
      <GroupName Descriptor="Administrator">
         <ID type="ID">1</ID>
         <ID type="Group">Administrator</ID>
      </GroupName>
      <Members Name="12345 / john smith ">
         <ID type="ID">1</ID>
         <ID type="UserID">12345</ID>
         <ID type="UserName">jsmith</ID>
      </Members>
   </Report>
   <Report>
      <GroupName Descriptor="User">
         <ID type="ID">1</ID>
         <ID type="Group">User</ID>
      </GroupName>
      <Members Name="14568/Bob smith">
         <ID type="ID">1</ID>
         <ID type="UserID">14568</ID>
         <ID type="UserName">bsmith</ID>
      </Members>
      <Members Name="14597/Tommy lee">
         <ID type="ID">1</ID>
         <ID type="UserID">14597</ID>
         <ID type="UserName">tlee</ID>
      </Members>
   </Report>
</Data>
```

I want list of users , something like -

```
jsmith Administrator
bsmith User
tlee   User
```

I tried Xpath and Descendants both didn't yield me the results I wanted

Comment: Where is your effort? Where is your c# code? Also, your desired output doesn't match the source XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<Group> groups = doc.Descendants("Report").Select(x => new Group()
            {
                groupName = (string)x.Element("GroupName").Attribute("Descriptor"),
                userNames = x.Elements("Members").Select(y => (string)y.Attribute("Name")).ToArray()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Group
    {
        public string groupName { get; set; }
        public string[] userNames { get;set;}
    }
}
```